# CSS and Javascript animation from codepen not working

Tags: javascript, css, animation, codepen

I have the following code from a codepen post that I have tried to re-create using a single html page. The design shows up fine, but the animation doesn't seem to work.

**The codepen link is here:**

https://codepen.io/MarcoGuglielmelli/pen/lLCxy

**The code I have** (copied from the above) and I have used the compiled CSS from codepen is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Header */
.large-header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 1;
}
#large-header {
  background-image: url("https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/img/demo-1-bg.jpg");
}
.main-title {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #f9f1e9;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.demo-1 .main-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4.2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.main-title .thin {
  font-weight: 200;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .demo-1 .main-title {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}

</style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="large-header" class="large-header">
  <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
    <h1 class="main-title"><span class="thin">TitleGoes <span class="thin">.here</span></h1>
</div>
<script>
(function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {x: width/2, y: height/2};

        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create points
        points = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < width; x = x + width/20) {
            for(var y = 0; y < height; y = y + height/20) {
                var px = x + Math.random()*width/20;
                var py = y + Math.random()*height/20;
                var p = {x: px, originX: px, y: py, originY: py };
                points.push(p);
            }
        }

        // for each point find the 5 closest points
        for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var closest = [];
            var p1 = points[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                var p2 = points[j]
                if(!(p1 == p2)) {
                    var placed = false;
                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(closest[k] == undefined) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            p1.closest = closest;
        }

        // assign a circle to each point
        for(var i in points) {
            var c = new Circle(points[i], 2+Math.random()*2, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
            points[i].circle = c;
        }
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    // animation
    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
        for(var i in points) {
            shiftPoint(points[i]);
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            for(var i in points) {
                // detect points in range
                if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.3;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.6;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.1;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.3;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.02;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.1;
                } else {
                    points[i].active = 0;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0;
                }

                drawLines(points[i]);
                points[i].circle.draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function shiftPoint(p) {
        TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX-50+Math.random()*100,
            y: p.originY-50+Math.random()*100, ease:Circ.easeInOut,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint(p);
            }});
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function drawLines(p) {
        if(!p.active) return;
        for(var i in p.closest) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ p.active+')';
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function Circle(pos,rad,color) {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.pos = pos || null;
            _this.radius = rad || null;
            _this.color = color || null;
        })();

        this.draw = function() {
            if(!_this.active) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ _this.active+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }

    // Util
    function getDistance(p1, p2) {
        return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
    }

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone point to the error (why is there no animation?) and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This codepen has a number of external resources listed. Try clicking on the 'cog' icon to the top left of each of the three windows, and you will see the external resources:

Try adding this to your `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400,800" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/css/demo.css" />

<script src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/rAF.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/AnimatedHeaderBg/demo-1/js/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you - but where do these need to be included and how? Given my example and context -

Comment: Editted to show how to include these files locally.

Comment: @noa-dev please have in mind that the post was edited after MissComputing asked this follow up question so this information was probably not even there

Comment: In his defence, I finished editing it at pretty much exactly the same time as he commented

Comment: Why on earth was the answer downvoted? This will undoubtedly help SO users who haven't used codepen before